# Take SHA-1 hash of a value and Base64 encoding it

Tags: java, shell, unix, base64

I need a shell command or shellscript that can take the following value

```
dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11
```

Then generate a SHA-1 hash of it, which is

```
0xb3 0x7a 0x4f 0x2c 0xc0 0x62 0x4f 0x16 0x90 0xf6
   0x46 0x06 0xcf 0x38 0x59 0x45 0xb2 0xbe 0xc4 0xea
```

and Encode this value using Base64 and it ends up like

```
s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
```

I can easily do this in Java using following code

```
String key = "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

//s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
System.out.println(Base64.encodeBase64String(md.digest(key.getBytes())));
```

So far I have tried

```
echo -n "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" | openssl sha1 -binary | base64
```

and just in case

```
echo -n "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" | openssl dgst -sha1  | base64
```

But they all print out wrong values.

Please give me some suggestions or help me out to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first attempt works for me, your second if you add `-binary` to the openssl command.

Comment: @ThomasFenzl shoot, it actually does work, I forgot to add 95CA-C5AB0DC85B11 part so it showed me a wrong value..

Comment: And you are correct, first one works as same as | open ssl dgst -sha1 -binary. Thanks for your help.